# What is the simplest scriptable way to check whether a shell variable is exported?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

For some shell sessions I want to be able to print a warning flag if a shell variable is not set and exported.

It is fairly simple to do something like this to print "Error" in the prompt if `SET_ME` is unset or null.

```
test_var () { test -z "$1" && echo Error; }
PS1='$(test_var "$SET_ME") \$ '
```

However this fails to flag if I set `SET_ME` without exporting it, which is an error that I want to be able to detect. Short of something like `$(bash -c 'test -z "$SET_ME" && echo Error;')` or grepping the output of `export`, is there a simple check that I can do to test whether `SET_ME` has been exported?

A non-POSIX, bash-only solution is completely acceptable.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `declare` command and the regular expression matching operator:

```
test_var () {
    # $1 - name of a shell variable
    var=$1
    [[ -z "${!var}" ]] && echo Error
    [[ $(declare -p $1)  =~ ^declare\ -[aAilrtu]*x[aAilrtu]*\  ]] || echo Error
}
```

Comment: I think that this is what I'm looking for. In theory, the re might need to be more flexible, e.g. if I had a read-only exported variable, but in practice I never use other `typeset` attributes.

Comment: Good point. I'll fix it for posterity.

Comment: It looks like attempting to quote the regular expression stops it working as a regular expression in bash >= 3.2.

Comment: Also there's an inconsistency, `-z "$1"` assumes I'm passing the value of a variable to `test_var` (as I was) whereas `declare -p` expects its name. I came up with this test which takes the name of a shell variable: `test_exported_notnull () { re='^declare -\w*x'; [[ -n $(eval echo \$$1) ]] && [[ $(declare -p "$1") =~ $re ]]; }` .

Comment: To avoid the `eval`, just add this first line: `var=$1`, then use `[[ -z "${!var}" ]] && echo Error`.

Comment: Why do you specify exact symbols in the checks surrounding `x` rather than `[^[:space:]]`?

Comment: At the time, I assumed the set was fixed and it was small enough to enumerate. I believe `n` has been added to the set since 2012, so something more general probably should be used. (Pattern matching would probably be simpler, though, so you could write `[[ $(declare -p $1) == declare\ -*x* ]]` instead.

Comment: I would also add `local var=$1` since otherwise you will have a global variable `var` hanging around.

Answer (score 12):

In **Bash 4.4 or later**, you can use the `${parameter@a}` [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to get a list of attributes about a parameter, including if it is exported.

Here is a simple function demonstrating `${parameter@a}`, that will tell you if a given variable is exported, given its name:

```
function is_exported {
    local name="$1"
    if [[ "${!name@a}" == *x* ]]; then
        echo "Yes - '$name' is exported."
    else
        echo "No - '$name' is not exported."
    fi
}
```

Example of use:

```
$ is_exported PATH
Yes - 'PATH' is exported.
$ foo=1 is_exported foo
Yes - 'abc' is exported.
$ bar=1; is_exported bar
No - 'abc' is not exported.
$ export baz=1; is_exported baz
Yes - 'baz' is exported.
$ export -n baz; is_exported baz
No - 'baz' is not exported.
$ declare -x qux=3; is_exported qux
Yes - 'qux' is exported.
```

How it works:

The format returned by `${parameter@a}` is one character per attribute, with the meaning of each attribute character coming from the corresponding options from the [declare command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) - in this case, we want to look for `x` - exported.

Comment: Best Answer if you are using Bash 4.4 or newer!

Answer (score 6):

I'm aware the question is 3 years old, however one may find following solution simpler:

```
[ "$(bash -c 'echo ${variable}')" ]
```

answers, if the variable is exported and has non-empty value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `compgen` with its `-X` option to determine if a variable is exported:

```
compgen -e -X "!$MAY_BE_EXPORTED_VARIABLE"
```

E.g.:

```
$ NOT_EXPORTED="xxx"
$ compgen -e -X '!SHELL'
SHELL
$ compgen -e -X '!NOT_EXPORTED'
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Best compatible answer! Over twice as slow as the ${parameter@a} solution, but far more compatible for bash 3.2 cases

Answer (score 2):

If I resign myself to having to use `export` and `grep`, the simplest test is probably something like this.

```
export | grep -Eq '^declare -x SET_ME='
```

or if I want non-null as well:

```
export | grep -Eq '^declare -x SET_ME=".+"'
```

Comment: [POSIX 7 says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_22) that `export` is unspecified, and defines a precise format for `export -p` similar to bash `export` but different. But bash seems to ignore POSIX and use the same format as `export` for `export -p`!

Answer (score 1):

The `export` command, given without parameters, gives a list of exported names in the current environment:

```
$ FOO1=test
$ FOO2=test
$ export | grep FOO
$ export FOO2
$ export | grep FOO
declare -x FOO2="test"
```

Some cutting and sed'ing gets rid of the fluff:

```
export | cut -d' ' -f 3- | sed s/=.*//
```

There's your list of exports, ready for further processing.

Comment: This does work but I was hoping for a lighter answer with fewer implied forks (hence "Short of [...] grepping the output of `export`") as my planned use is in my prompt.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I see. I came to this by searching the bash manpage for `export`, and this was the only thing I came up with. No help from the shell escapes either. The `export` is builtin anyway, but I doubt you can avoid the `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I currently can think of:

```
[ bash -c ': ${v1?}' 2>/dev/null ]
```